# Latex not breaking lines of text correctly with unusual paper dimensions

Tags: paper-size

I am trying to make a document with unusual dimensions, in this case 4.125in by 9.5in, but LaTeX will not break the lines of text correctly and the margins are not as expected either.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\eject \pdfpagewidth=4.125in \pdfpageheight=9.5in
\lipsum[150]
\end{document}
```

This gives me (note the margin on the left side):

[image]

Ideally it would look the same as a normal document just on a smaller piece of paper. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've provided the page size dimensions -- what about the text block dimensions within the (logical) page?

Comment: Maybe you want something like `\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=4.125in,paperheight=9.5in,margin=5pt}` in your preamble (you may want to adjust the `margin` value).

Comment: @Werner That works great. How would I go about resizing the paper size later in the code?

Comment: `geometry` provides the commands `newgeometry` and `restoregeometry`. But note that continually changing the size of the page/paper is not trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of lengths/dimensions involved in setting content on a page, not just the page width/height. For example, see Figure 1 of the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf):

[image]

My suggestion would be to use `geometry` to specify your page dimensions. Based on your specifications, you may be interested in the following layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=4.125in,paperheight=9.5in,margin=5pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\sloppy\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Adjust the value for `margin` to suit your needs.

Comment: @Dan: `\newgeometry{<settings>}` would flush the current page and start a new one with the new `<settings>` (similar to my example). `\restoregeometry` would revert back to whatever it was before `\newgeometry`, again flushing the page before applying the settings. It's not that easy to have continuous flow of content between these geometry changes, but that is also assumed as it would be strange from the viewer's/reader's perspective.